# Nextjs typescript filtering table with checkboxes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sorting, next.js, filtering

Ive recently started with Typescript and I am stuck with a problem.
In javascript I solved the problem but now in Typescript i fundle in the dark.
I got data from an api and a table where I use a filtering method to populate the data for the table.
What I need help with is to fix sorting and filtering by checkboxes.
I have embedded a link to a codesandbox to reproduce my problem.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-feistel-isspt?file=/pages/index.tsx

````
      const elavtal: { [key: string]: any } = [
        { productTypeLabel: "SPOT" },
        { productTypeLabel: "HOURLY SPOT" },
        { productTypeLabel: "FIXED" },
        { productTypeLabel: "BUY PRICE" }
      ];
        {elavtal.map((elavtal, i) => {
                                return (
                                  <input type="checkbox" key={i} defaultChecked={false} value={elavtal.productTypeLabel}
                                    onChange={(event) =>
                                      setProductType((prev) =>
                                        event.target.checked
                                          ? [...prev, elavtal.productTypeLabel]
                                          : []
                                      )
                                    }
                                  >{elavtal.productTypeLabel}</input>
                                )
                              })
                              }```
````

Answer (score 0):

define your interface "IElAvtal" as an object and use an array of objects "IElAvtal[]"

```
interface IElAvtal {
  productTypeLabel: string;
}

const elavtal: IElAvtal[] = [
  { productTypeLabel: "SPOT" },
  { productTypeLabel: "HOURLY SPOT" },
  { productTypeLabel: "FIXED" },
  { productTypeLabel: "BUY PRICE" }
];

elavtal.map((el, i) => {
  return (
     ...
  )
}
```